# How to use star notation in host file to block multiple websites?

Tags: hosts-file

Host file allows to block a site (games.com)

Is there way to use host file to block multiple websites sharing a domain? 
Assume the user wants to block racing.games.com and chase.games.com and arcade.games.com.

Can I enter something in the spirit of "*.games.com"?
There are 20+ subdomains and it is tedious to do it one by one.

Answer (score 1):

If they don't use a CDN then do a whois on the domain and look for CIDR.  Then block the CIDR range.  If they are using a CDN then this will block way more that you want it to.